# MySQL conditional JOIN using keys from different tables for matching

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements

I have read and learned a lot here, got a lot of problems solved without asking anything so far, but I couldn't cope with this one.

I have three tables:

```
-programs
 ->ProgramID (Primary Unique)
 ->ProgramName
 ->AuditID

-audits
 ->AuditID (Primary Unique)
 ->VenueName
 ->Address

-events
 ->EventID (Primary Unique)
 ->EventDate
 ->ProgramID
 ->AuditID
```

**Events** are instances of those programs that are on stage that day. *Multiple instances* of one program might be performed on one day, *or none* if it's not played. This is basically a temporary table, repopulated daily. Tickets can be bought from programs that are played on said day.

**Audits** are the actual stages where the plays are performed. A theatre can have several stages.

**Programs** are plays for theatres that are on their repertoire for years. The last stage where it was is performed is stored for when someone retrieves the information of a program that is not played on the actual day the stage can still be linked.

I am using this query now:

```
SELECT
    programs.ProgramID,
    programs.ProgramName,
    programs.AuditID,
    events.EventID,
    events.EventDate,
    audits.VenueName,
    audits.Address
FROM programs
LEFT JOIN events
ON programs.ProgramID = events.ProgramID
JOIN audits
ON programs.AuditID = audits.AuditID
WHERE programs.ProgramID = :ProgramID
```

- If there is no event of that program the LEFT JOIN gives me information about the program and the audit leaving the event info blank. Good.
- Also okay when the event is at the same audit where it was played last time. Great.
- The problem is if it's played in a different audit, because the JOIN for the audits table is made based on programs.AuditID key, which is obsolete now.

What I would need is a conditional JOIN, so that when the events.AuditID is not null, the audits table is joined using events.AuditID instead of programs.AuditID.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be able to `JOIN` using `IFNULL(events.AuditID, programs.AuditID)` to solve this problem...

```
SELECT
    programs.ProgramID,
    programs.ProgramName,
    programs.AuditID,
    events.EventID,
    events.EventDate,
    audits.VenueName,
    audits.Address
FROM programs
LEFT JOIN events
ON programs.ProgramID = events.ProgramID
JOIN audits
ON IFNULL(events.AuditID, programs.AuditID) = audits.AuditID
WHERE programs.ProgramID = :ProgramID
```

Comment: gives this error : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL

this says it should have only one parameter: [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull)

Comment: `ISNULL` probably wanted to be an `IFNULL`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: @biziclop Thank you, sir... you're correct.  Switching between MySql and Sql Server is going to make my head explode...

Comment: Works a treat! You wouldn't believe how many futile attempts I made and how much time I wasted on this simple query. Thank you @Michael! Köszönöm @biziclop!